# What's the grammatical function of the following phrase in bold?

Tags: terminology

I'm not sure if the phrase in bold in the following context is an example of an adjunct in grammar. To my knowledge, adjuncts are usually adverb groups or prepositional phrases.

> In everyday practice, however, concentric rather than territorial
> forms of social organization, **reminiscent of earlier concepts of
> locality**, continued to be effective.

Comment: It looks more like a supplement than an adjunct.